# Pure js count caracte input in case of multilanguage

Tags: javascript

I try to count the character inside different input in a loop. The count does not appear (not work.
I am not it's a good approach to that.
Thank you.

```
         <?php
 for ($i = 0, $n = \count($languages); $i < $n; $i++) {
    echo '
    <script>
        var maxchar' . $i . ' = 70;
        var i' . $i . ' = document.getElementById("SeoTitle' . $i . '");
        var c' . $i . ' = document.getElementById("count");
        c' . $i . '.innerHTML = maxchar' . $i . ';
    
        i' . $i . '.addEventListener("keydown",count);
    
        function count(e){
            var len =  i' . $i . '.value.length;
            if (len >= maxchar' . $i . '){
                e.preventDefault();
            } else{
                c' . $i . '.innerHTML = maxchar' . $i . ' - len-1;
            }
        }
    ?>    
</script>';
```

HTML

```
 echo HTML::inputField('categories_head_title_tag[' . $languages[$i]['id'] . ']', null, 'maxlength="70" size="77" id="SeoTitle' . $i . '"', false); 
?>
 <span id="count<?php echo $i; ?>"></span>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: why not take an array of all instead numbering variables?

Comment: I am not good with th js.